# Use time.time() on Linux for profiling

Tags: python, time, profiling

`time.time()` on Linux seems to produce current time in `us = 1/1000 ms` precision.

Can I use that to profile functions in `ms` precision, by doing this:

```
func_start = time.time() * 1000
#run something inbetween
print 'Function finishes in: %.3f ms' % ((time.time() * 1000) - func_start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't increase the precision that way. You could just as well do:

```
func_start = time.time()

print 'Function finishes in: %.3f ms' % ((time.time() - func_start) * 1000)
```

but to measure performance of a function accurately, you really need to re-run it several times to remove the effects of OS scheduling, coinciding disk flush interrupts, etc.

For timing methods as accurately as your platform will allow, use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), or at least re-use it's [`default_timer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) function.